# 0/10V @ 5 mA input ,translated to 0/10V @0,2A output

Tags: level-shifting

The idea is a circuit where an analog input 0-10V (max current of 5mA input), reflects into an analog output with a minimum current of 200mA. The voltage of the analog output (Vo) must always be equal to the analog input voltage (Vi), ie Vo = Vi (gain = 1) The circuit should be powered on 24VDC, where the current gain should come from this source . The circuit must have terminal necessary for the connection.

Any sugestion ?

Comment: Include a circuit please, ask a question of what you really want to do with specifics. Your question is too broad. Are you trying to power something? Your job is to understand the circuit and ask questions about it, so follow the forum rules and do some research then after you have come up with a semblance of a design, ask your question.

Comment: What you are looking for is a "buffer", or more correctly a unity gain non-inverting buffer. You can design one using discreet parts, or buy an IC that implements it in a single chip. I don't understand your statement "where the current gain should come from this source". What do you mean?

Comment: The OP means that output current should come from the 24 V supply. See my answer (and improve, if you like).

Answer (score 3):

Are you just looking for a 0 - 10 V, unity gain amplifier with current source capability of 200 mA?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fTzfts.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. Unity gain current amplifer.*

This circuit should get you on your way. You need an op-amp that can swing to negative rail.

Comment: why Q1?, Can it be implemented using opamp only?

Comment: I never saw an op-amp with a 200 mA output drive capability - but I never looked for one. Do you know of one? The emitter follower configuration offloads the 'grunt' work to the transistor. Taking the feedback signal from the emitter means the op-amp will compensate for the base-emitter voltage drop.

Comment: I have not checked all the parameters but here is a high current opamp. http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/opa549.pdf

Comment: Yes , it works from about 2 V above .I will now to provide at least  - 3V and chek it out .Problem now is to folow down to zero volts As far  OPA549 I'll try to find one  . Thanks very much for the hints !